# Sharing same git submodule for both project

Tags: git, git-submodules

So i've a 3 project A, B and C

Project A is the core library
Project B is an extension of A (so project A is requiered to work)
Project C is an application build with project A & B

Project A
|            |
|            |
|        Project B
|            |
|            |
Project C

My projects setup are like this

ProjectA/srcs/

ProjectB/lib/ProjectA (submodule)
ProjectB/srcs/

**ProjectC/lib/ProjectA** (submodule)
ProjectC/lib/ProjectB (submodule)
**ProjectC/lib/ProjectB/lib/ProjectA** (submodule)
ProjectC/srcs

How can i use the same ProjectA (bold) submodule in ProjectC without modifying ProjectB ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I would use symlinks to achieve the goal.

That is if `ProjectC` needs the same version of `ProjectA` as `ProjectB` make

`ProjectC/lib/ProjectA` to be a symlink to `../ProjectB/lib/ProjectA`