# How to include only one copy of a git submodule that multiple C# projects depend on within a solution?

Tags: c#, windows, git

Several of our C# projects have dependencies on multiple C# libraries, with those libraries often used by multiple different C# programs. The libraries themselves also often have dependencies on other C# libraries.

So, for example, application A may depend on libraries X and Y, which each in turn depend on library Z. Applications B, C, and D may also have dependencies on libraries X, Y, and/or Z.

Within Subversion, this is relatively easy to deal with: each of the reusable libraries has a repository which contains the Visual Studio solution file at the root of a given branch and then each project (i.e. the library project in question as well as test app projects, unit test projects, etc.) has its own folder under that. For libraries that have dependencies on other libraries from other repositories, the relevant library folders of the dependencies are then included at that same level as SVN externals. Programs which use these libraries then also include the needed library folders as SVN externals under the root of a given branch with the solution file again in the root. This works great and simply checking out a given branch of a given application or library will automatically grab that application or library's project as well as those of all of its dependencies and everything is ready to build. Each external reference is also tied to a particular revision of the repository it's referencing, so one of the libraries being updated will not break the builds of projects that depend on it.

So, continuing with the above example, if I check out a branch of application A, I get a working copy with A's solution file, A's project folder, and the project folders of libraries X, Y, and Z and everything is ready to build. Similarly, if I check out a branch of library X, I get a working copy with X's solution file, X's project folder, and Z's project folder, again all ready to build.

I am looking for a way to accomplish the above with Git (in case it matters, hosted by Github.) Clients will be running Windows with Visual Studio.

While I have seen Git submodules, I have not yet found a way to replicate the above-described behavior in cases where multiple submodules that each themselves include a common submodule can be included from an application's (or library's) repository wherein a clone will result in a working copy containing that application's (or library's) solution file and project folder, along with *only one copy* of the project folder of each of the libraries that the application or any of its dependencies depends on.

It seems that, at least by default, having application A in a repository that includes submodules of X and Y would result in something like:

```
- A (solution)
|- A (project)
 |- X (project)
   |- Z (project)
 |- Y (project)
   |- Z (project)
```

(with X and Y each containing an independent copy of Z)

rather than the desired:

```
- A (solution)
|- A (project)
|- X (project)
|- Y (project)
|- Z (project)
```

(with only one copy of each dependency and all project folders being siblings)

Is there a way to accomplish the latter result with Git?

Solutions that use only standard Git features that would be supported by any client are preferred, but if there's a way to do this using only certain Git clients, I'm ok with that, too, at least so long as those clients run on Windows.

I would strongly prefer to avoid solutions that rely on running a script (or taking other steps after a clone) to create symlinks or similar.

---

I have seen several other related questions (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51051342/1890705), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60239281/1890705), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4115817/1890705),) but the suggested solutions all seem to involve needing a run a bunch of OS-specific commands to create symlinks (or hard links) and such after doing a clone, which I'd very much like to avoid. Ideally, a clone would initiate a one-step (from the user's perspective) process that places everything where it needs to be (with the actual source code and project files in working copies, not, for example, nuget packages.)

Most of the questions on this subject also seem to be older, so I was curious if any changes to Git over the years may have provided a more elegant solution than what has been previously discussed in the other questions I've seen.

Comment: "*Most of the questions on this subject also seem to be older, so I was curious if any changes to Git over the years may have provided a more elegant solution than what has been previously discussed in the other questions I've seen.*" Nope, nothing changed. Shared submodules are duplicated.

Comment: "*…a clone would initiate a one-step (from the user's perspective) process that places everything where it needs to be…*" Impossible. Every superproject stores commit IDs for all its direct submodules and that's where the problem lies. Git cannot guess in advance some of your submodules are shared on the same commit ID so Git must clone all copies of the shared submodules and checkout stored commits. And there is no post-clone hook. So one must do full clone and then cleanup, no way around that.

Comment: @phd With SVN, URL+revision is also stored for each external, but SVN externals can be to subfolders, so you can accomplish what I described by application A having external references for X, Y, and Z (rather than depending on X and Y to recursively pull in Z.) As long as all projects expect their project folders to be siblings of each other (which is normal for VS/C# anyway,) this works fine. I suppose this is not possible with git submodules due to submodules not being able to target a specific subfolder rather than the whole repo? (I'll upvote that if you put it in an answer, btw.)

Comment: I didn't use SVN for more then 10 years so I don't remember details. But how would SVN externals solve the problem of shared externals? If X and Y both points to different versions of Z shouldn't SVN checkout 2 different copies of Z?

Comment: @phd At least the way I'm accustomed to using SVN with C# solutions, I set up svn:externals on each solution and it pulls each dependency (including dependencies of dependencies) in directly. It does not rely on dependencies to bring in their own dependencies, so there's only ever one copy of each in a working copy. Pulling two different versions of Z would not work in a normal C# project, as they would overwrite each other in the final output directory of the application, both having the same file name.

Answer (score 1):

> *…a clone would initiate a one-step (from the user's perspective) process that places everything where it needs to be…*

Impossible. Every superproject stores commit IDs for all its direct submodules and that's where the problem lies. Git cannot guess in advance some of your submodules are shared on the same commit ID so Git must clone all copies of the shared submodules and checkout stored commits. And there is no post-clone hook. So one must do full clone and then cleanup, no way around that.

> *I suppose this is not possible with git submodules due to submodules not being able to target a specific subfolder rather than the whole repo?*

To some extent, yes. It's an orthogonal problem to commit IDs stored in the superprojects.